# Get submitted values of webform in hook_alter function

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

how can i get the submitted field values of webform in hook_alter function.
One more question is how can i call to submit function from hook_alter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hook_alter_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) is only invoked during form array *build time*, not when the form is submitted, so it's not possible (as is trying to submit a form that isn't rendered to the browser yet). If you want to handle the submitted form values for your own custom processing, add a submit handler to the form array.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_ID') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_webform_client_form_ID_submit';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_webform_client_form_ID_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // @TODO: process $form_state['values'] as needed.
}
```